# Spark S3 null uri host

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder
          .appName(appName)
          .config("spark.delta.logStore.class", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.storage.S3SingleDriverLogStore")
          .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
          .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
          .config("hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions", 5000)
          .config("hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode", 5000)
          .enableHiveSupport()
          .master("local[2]")
          .getOrCreate()
spark
    .sparkContext
    .hadoopConfiguration
    .set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
spark.read.json("s3a:///bucketname/foldername/").inputFiles
```

Raises the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: null uri host.
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.S3xLoginHelper.buildFSURI(S3xLoginHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.setUri(S3AFileSystem.java:470)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3352)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:547)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:545)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:545)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:391)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:325)
```

I have verified that I am able to read from the bucket and have the correct permissions.

Comment: I got this error (and some unhelpful message about a possible un-encoded '/' character in password) and had slightly misspelled my bucket name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently I was missing the bucket name from the path. Also used `s3a://` instead of `s3a:///`

Comment: thanks. For me it works with 2 `/` and not `3` but my bucket name was wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a period `.` in my s3 bucket name which did not conform to a top level domain pattern. This is not supported by the URI in Scala. Once I changed my bucket and removed the period, it started working.

> buckets can contain dots and s3a will work, but only if these bucket names conform to hostname restrictions - e.g. `s3a://foo.bar/bak.csv` would work, but my case - `okokes-test-v1.1` does not, because `1` is not conform to a top level domain pattern.

Reference: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-17241